# add \0 in the middle of char pointer

Tags: c, pointers, memory

I have a bigger string and I want to add the \0 character before a specific string is contained.

ex:

inputString = "some2.text.here"; => outputText = "some2";

I manage to find the last position of the output text, I don't know how to add \0 and make the pointer end here.

```
void test()
{
    char* str = "some2.text.here";
    char* search = ".text.here";
    char * new;
    //size text to be removed
    int lengthOfStr = 10; //search length
    int size = 0;
    char stringEnding = '\0';
    char * newPath;
   
    new = '\0';
    for(int i = 0; i < 200; i++){
        if(*(str + i) == '\0'){
            printf("found on index %d", i);
            printf("\n i: %d \n lengthOfStr : %d", i, lengthOfStr);
            new = (char *) malloc(i - lengthOfStr);
            memcpy(new, str, sizeof(i - lengthOfStr));
            break;

        }
    }
    printf("\n string value : %s", new);
}
```

Here I try to copy a specific length but is not working well... I also tried to add str[5] = '\0'but also did not did the trick... Any tips?

Comment: The result of `i - lengthOfStr` is an `int`, so `sizeof(i - lengthOfStr)` is really `sizeof(int)`. You want the actual size calculated by `i - lengthOfStr`. And remember to allocate one extra character for the null-terminator.

Comment: Also `new = '\0'` is a confusing way of setting `new` to a NULL pointer (character `'\0'` is the integer 0 which means a null pointer).  It doesn't matter here since you never use it, but if you wanted `new` to point to an empty string, use `new = ""` instead.

Comment: OT: `*(str + i)` -> `str[i]` for readability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be 3 problems.

1. Too little memory allocated
2. Wrong number of bytes copied
3. Missing string termination

Something like:

```
        new = malloc(i - lengthOfStr + 1);          // Allocate 1 more char
        memcpy(new, str, i - lengthOfStr);          // Correct number of bytes to copy
        new[i - lengthOfStr] = '\0';                // Terminate the string
```

BTW: Your current code always expects the "search" string to be in the end of the current string. Maybe that's what you want but it seems to me that you should use `strstr` instead of a loop. And... use `strlen` instead of a hard code length.

Comment: Your solution works, this code will replace extensions and that's why I always want to find the ending. I agree it can be improved in many ways.